# Promoted links change to relative url

Tags: sharepoint-online, promoted-links

I have a SP site at `https://site1.domain.com` (with FBA login). Inside there is a page with "Promoted Links".

All its links are going to `https://site1.domain.com/whatever.aspx` except one that goes to `https://site2.domain.com` (with FBA login too).
When I edit the Location Link that takes me from site1 to site2, the link automatically changes to a relative url.

For example:

I type Location link: `https://site2.domain.com/_layouts/15/name.folder/myPage.aspx`,
but after save, the link on the page looks like `https://site1.domain.com/_layouts/15/name.folder/myPage.aspx.`
When I come back to edit again the link has become a relative url: `/_layouts/15/name.folder/myPage.aspx`.

I have tried almost everything with the same result. Editing, Deleting, Creating a new one, etc.

Don't know what else to do!

My theory is that because the user in the site1 does not have administrator permissions in the site2, SharePoint recognizes this and doesn't allow the user to edit the location link to a site that he doesn't have enough permissions.

Any comments?

Comment: I changed the title to reflect what the issue really is, if you feel it's not right, you can revert the changes.

Comment: "promoted links" copose it self like this:

Avery the <a href="#" onCLick="PreventDefaultNavigation(); return false;" hrefaction="link_i_want_to_change.aspx">

I use JQuery (I did not want to)

$("a[hrefaction='here_goes_the_relative_link']").unbind(); //this clean events
$("a[hrefaction='here_goes_the_relative_link']").attr("hrefaction", "here_goes_my_new_link"); //this assign new value to hrefaction attribute

I had to do this, because all item has de same structure, label, class, etc.. and the "ids" can change.
So. I solve this BUT i still want to know if the Promoted Links has this issue.